# Calling python from perl - methods are not calling properly

Tags: python, perl

I am trying to call python script from a Perl script. python script importing another python file. Perl file and python files are placed into different directories. When I am trying to run python script directly, it calls the constructor of import python file and another method of import file and working successfully. However, When I was trying to do the same from Perl script the only constructor is called.

Utility.py

```
Class DemoCheck :
   def Hello():
   print("Hello")

   Utility(self):
   print("Constructor calling")
```

run.py

```
import Utility
const = Utility.DemoCheck
const.Hello()
```

When I am running `run.py` directly. The output will be first constructor print then hello method print.
When I am trying to call it from Perl script `python /app/python/run.py` the only constructor is print not hello method print.

Both python directories are placed into folder `/app/python` and Perl script present into folder `app/perl`.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unrelated to Perl, and is entirely due to the directory from which you run your Python script.

When you `import` a Python module, the module is searched for in the directories listed in `sys.path`. This includes the location of the standard library, and the current directory. So everything works when you run from the directory that includes the `Utility.py` file.

Here, there are four sensible solutions you might apply:

- Change the current directory to app/python before launching the Python script.
- Add the location of your modules to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.
- Better: Turn your Python script into a package that can be installed, and install it on your system, so that its modules are available from the locations where Python looks by default.
- Even better: use relative imports so that the `sys.path` lookup is avoided entirely:

  ```py
  from .Utility import DemoCheck
  #    ^--
  DemoCheck().Hello()
  ```

  However, that requires the two modules to have a parent package, i.e. be part of some `__init__.py` directory that was loaded first.